# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar el tabpage?

Tags: c#

Tengo un tabpage donde creo de forma dinámica label ,textbox y combobox. Se actualiza desde una base de datos **sqlite**.

el codigo es el siguiente

```
        int y = 60;
        string Nombre="";


       Entidades.Identificador [] listado= db.MostrarCriterio();
       for (int i = 0; i < listado.Length; i++)
       {
           if (listado[i].getSelect()=="True")
           {
               Nombre = listado[i].getNombre().ToString();


               Label myText = new Label();
               myText.Location = new Point(72, y);
               myText.Text = Nombre;



               this.Controls.Add(myText);
               this.tabPage3.Controls.Add(myText);



               TextBox mybox = new TextBox();
               mybox.Location = new Point(300, y);
               mybox.Size = new Size(100, 200);
               // this.Controls.Add(myText);
               this.Controls.Add(mybox);
               this.tabPage3.Controls.Add(mybox);
               y += 40;



           }
           else
           {
               Nombre = listado[i].getNombre().ToString();
               Label myText1 = new Label();
               myText1.Location = new Point(72, y);
               myText1.Text = Nombre;


               this.Controls.Add(myText1);
               this.tabPage3.Controls.Add(myText1);
               ComboBox micombobox = new ComboBox();
               micombobox.Location = new Point(300, y);
               micombobox.Size = new Size(100, 200);

               this.Controls.Add(micombobox);
               this.tabPage3.Controls.Add(micombobox);

               y += 40;


           }

       }
```

Comment: No entiendo porque agregas los controles al Form y luego al tabPage3. Para ver tus controles luego que los agregas puedes intentar con un `tabPage3.Refresh();` o incluso refrescando la forma entera `this.Refresh();`

Comment: ya probe las recomendaciones pero sigue mostrandome el control creado a pesar de que lo borre en la base de datos.

Comment: Es que estas agregando los objetos en el código y no en base a la consulta a tu DB. Tienes un problema conceptual.

Comment: Supongo que si no quieres ver los borrados, lo mas sencillo es un `tabPage3.Controls.Clear();` esto antes del `foreach`

Comment: me funciono el codigo  tabPage3.Controls.Clear(), pero en el tabpage tengo un boton que el que activo para que me cree los controles dinamicos, existe alguna forma que no me borre ese boton cuando me limpie el tabpage.

Comment: como puedo guardar los valores de los controles que se crean en ese ejemplo, para despues adicionarlos a una base de datos sqlite